# Retrieving the list of all the Python APIs given by an application

Tags: c++, python, c, api, python-3.x

i would like to retrieve the list of all the APIs that an application is giving to the users.

The Application is written in C/C++ for the biggest part.

I was hoping that python has a standard function for that, i was also trying to approach this in terms of namespaces, since i'm not interested in all the keywords but only in the ones provided with the APIs, but i simply do not know where to start in terms of functions, i do not know about functions that are doing something related to what i'm trying to achieve.

The application uses Python 3.x to provide APIs.

Comment: How does it provide them? As public objects, classes and modules? As an HTTP API?

Comment: @Joe i would like to do this for several applications, but to make thing simpler let's say that i just want to focus on http://www.blender.org/ and here they are the APIs http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_63_17/contents.html .

Comment: So this is providing an access layer through Python objects.

Comment: @Joe and it's possible to do what i'm trying to do?

Comment: the dir/help function is your friend?

Comment: @pythonm not really because most of the times this Applications have a basic set of functions and many other namespaces or modules that you can import, dir() just show me what is already inside the namespace and not all the possible modules.

Comment: @pythonm it's the same as the _vanilla_ version of python and doesn't look like it can help too much, i can't get the list of modules or keywords from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't have a notion of an API (or *interface*) as a language primitive. A module or package will expose some of its members (functions and variables) and hide others, so if you know *which* modules you are interested in, "exposing" in this sense is AFAIK the most meaningful concept.

The exposed members are the same ones that will be imported if you run `from <module> import *`. As you probably know, member names that begin with a single underscore, or [begin with two underscores](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) and do *not* end with two, are not meant to be part of the API and will not be exported; by default everything else will be exposed, but a module can customize its API by listing what should be exported in the `__all__` variable-- see [Importing * from a package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

So, to find the APIs you are looking for you must first know which top-level modules you are interested in. If the application in question is available to python as a single package, start with it. If it has a `__all__` variable, its contents are the API for the package. If it does not, look through the contents of `dir(<package>)` and exclude anything that starts with only a single underscore, or starts with two underscores but does not end with two. If you're looking at a large package, some of what you'll find are themselves modules or packages. Examine them the same way, recursively.